# Can C++ reference refer to another object?

Tags: c++

I learned that once a reference is initialized to an object, it cannot refer to another object.
I wanted to try that myself. This is what I tried:

```
struct X
{
    int s;
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    X x2;

    X& xRef = x1;
    xRef = x2;

    X* xPtr = &x1;
    xPtr = &x2;
}
```

This code compiles without problems.
Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles because it is valid C++, it just doesn't happen to do what you think it does.

```
xRef = x2;
```

This line does exactly the same thing as:

```
x1 = x2;
```

Because `xRef` is a reference to `x1` you are actually assigning the value of `x2` to `x1`.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;

int & a_ref = a;
a_ref = b;

b = 7;

std::cout << "a:" << a << " b:" << b << std::endl;
```

This will show that the value of `a` is 6 (due to the line `a_ref = b;`) and `b` is 7.

The C++ language does not contain any mechanism by which you can rebind a reference.  Once bound, a reference only ever refers to the same object and this *cannot* be changed.